# Why is my psycopg2 query failing with `psycopg2.errors.InternalError_: Assert`?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm running [psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/index.html) on Python 3.9, querying a Redshift table.

I'm querying a table with a `SELECT *` passed to the `cursor.execute()` method:

```py
query = 'select * from my_schema.my_table;'
cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor) # psycopg2 connection
cursor.execute(query)
data = cursor.fetchall()
```

And, I'm getting back the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mypython.py", <lines>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 236, in execute
    return super().execute(query, vars)
psycopg2.errors.InternalError_: Assert
DETAIL:
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   status == 0 - timestamp: '-9223372036854775808'
  query:     <query #>
  location:  cg_util.cpp:705
  process:   <process>
  -----------------------------------------------
```

I can query other tables in different schema and the same schema, but not this table.

The table has `varchar` and `timestamp` column types. I'm using the `-infinity` [Special Date/Time Input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-TABLE) in one of the columns.

Comment: what happens if you remove "cursor_factory=RealDictCursor"?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `-infinity` timestamp value, psycopg2 doesn't seem to be agreeable to it.

In this case, I'm able to use a different built-in value, since my actual reason for using `-infinity` is to have a value that means "long ago".

```sql
update my_schema.my_table
set ts_column = timestamp 'epoch'
where my_table.ts_column = timestamp '-infinity';
```

Comment: No, the issue is Python does not support `+-infinity`. If you want a solution see here [Date adaptation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-date) and look for section 'Infinite dates handling'.